# Can't display data from API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new in react. I want to display data from API, but I got error.
This is how I displayed it. Can anyone help me what should I call the data? check my code https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-brown-y4cdq?file=/src/App.js

```
return (
<div>     
  <p>Dev Hooks App </p>
  <ul>
  {data.map(item =>(
    <li> {item.result.name}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>
 );
```

And my data looks like this

```
{
"count": 82,
"next": "http://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2",
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "name": "Luke Skywalker",
        "height": "172",
        "mass": "77",
        "hair_color": "blond",
        "skin_color": "fair",
        "eye_color": "blue",
        "birth_year": "19BBY",
        "gender": "male",
        "homeworld": "",
        "films": [],
        "species": [],
        },
       ]
      }
```

Comment: use `data.results.map` instead of `data.map` and `item.name` instead of `item.result.name`

Comment: I changed it, and still got error. The error is in <ul> . I don;t know what's wrong with <ul>

Comment: check here - https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-lehmann-j3rsq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: why my code get this error https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-brown-y4cdq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-lichterman-k0jf1?file=/src/App.js, here is the updated version of your code. Also you need to add dependency on useEffect method otherwise it will keep invoking after any component update.

Comment: Thank You @VarunArya

Answer (score 1):

Result is an array itself.so you need to either give index to get the each value or the above answers stating replace
data.result.map instead of data.map and item.name instead of item.result.name.

Answer (score 0):

Use data.results.map instead of data.map. Also replace item.result.name

Comment: Please check the the tick next to the answer if this worked

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't be:

```
return (
<div>     
  <p>Dev Hooks App </p>
  <ul>
  {data.results.map(item =>(
    <li> {item.name}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div> );
```